# Force doxygen to ignore class extensions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

Is there a way to force doxygen to ignore all class extensions in an Objective-C project without using preprocessor directives?

I use class extensions extensively in my `Class.m` files for my private attributes. When I use doxygen to generate documentation for my application, the generated class list includes all of my "secret" class extensions. I would like to hide these extensions from the generated documentation.

I can get doxygen to ignore a particular class extension by using the doxygen preprocessor and surrounding the extension in the `Class.m` with a `#ifndef/#endif`. I really don't like adding this to all of my `Class.m` files that have the internal extensions, because I feel that I am adding more clutter to my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class extensions can be excluded without changing the source code. This can be done by listing the class extensions in the `exclude_symbols` setting. See the sample screenshot: [image: Doxygen Settings To Exclude Class Extensions]

Answer (score 2):

If you want exclude *all* the class continuation add this row to the Doxy file

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = *()
```